# How to convert base64Binary string to image in Android?

Tags: android, base64

i tried this code

```
 byte decodedIcon[] = null;
 byte[] bb = (resposeString).getBytes("utf-8");
 decodedIcon = Base64.decodeBase64(bb);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedIcon, 0,decodedIcon.length);
```

I included commons-codec-1.3.jar

Still it returns null, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is null decodedIcon or Bitmap? are you getting any error in lagcat?

Comment: It is returning bitmap as  null

Answer (score 0):

I use Following function for convert Base64 String to Image.

```
public Bitmap Base64ToImage(String base64String) {
    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64String.getBytes(),
            Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0,
            imageAsBytes.length);
    return mybitmap;
}
```